# GraphicsMagick convert utility exit statuses

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm trying to write a partial Java (err... scala) wrapper to ImageMagick convert utility. I was wondering if the exit codes of the command are documented somewhere, or available in a single C / C++ file. I can't go over the entire code base at the moment. I've got a similar error code list for ImageMagick, was wondering if there was an equivalent in GraphicsMagick. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am looking for the same info, Did you find any?

Comment: I didn't. Instead I took the stderr and passed it along.

Comment: @RNA certainly too late, but there is now an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The below is quoted verbatim from an email reply from the key maintainer of graphicsmagick, Bob Friesenhahn.

"It returns only the simple values 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS) or 1 (EXIT_FAILURE).  Being highly portable software, it does not do anything fancy."